# ¿Por qué recibo este error? "TypeError: getVar() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Me aparece este error, no se por qué :(

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pruebaError.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(mostrarT())   
  File "pruebaError.py", line 22, in mostrarT
    if(t[i][j].getVar() == False):
TypeError: getVar() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Este es el código:

```
class A:
 var = False
 def __init__(self,var):
    self.var = var

 def getVar():
    return var

t = []
for i in range(8):
   t.append([None])
   for j in range(8):
       t[i].append(None)

for i in range(8):
   for j in range(8):
      t[i][j] = A(True)

def mostrarT():
    cantFalse = 0
    for i in range(8):
        for j in range(8):
            if(t[i][j].getVar()):
                cantFalse += 1
    return cantFalse                            
print(mostrarT())
```

Comment: prueba definiendo `getVar` como estático, agregar  `@staticmethod` antes del def, o pasarle self como parámetro

Comment: Debes indicar una variable para la instancia del objeto, por ej.  `def getVar(self):`

Answer (score 1):

Al usar clases en python tienes que pasar el parametro self que es la instancia de la clase en todas tus funciones que definas, también tienes que usar self para acceder al variable que quieres acceder

quedaria asi:

```
class A:
 var = False
 def __init__(self,var):
    self.var = var

 def getVar(self):
    return self.var

t = []
for i in range(8):
   t.append([None])
   for j in range(8):
       t[i].append(None)

for i in range(8):
   for j in range(8):
      t[i][j] = A(True)

def mostrarT():
    cantFalse = 0
    for i in range(8):
        for j in range(8):
            if(t[i][j].getVar()):
                cantFalse += 1
    return cantFalse                            
print(mostrarT())
```